# Print each data from geolocation api in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, geolocation

I want to print all info from geolocation API in codeigniter then I want to insert into database. I try to print using foreach but find an error,

```
    $ip='202.6x.xx.xx';
    $this->load->library('Geolocation');
    $this->load->config('geolocation', true);
    $config = $this->config->config['geolocation'];
    $this->geolocation->initialize($config);
    $this->geolocation->set_ip_address($ip);
    $country = $this->geolocation->get_country();
    //var_dump($country);

    $city = $this->geolocation->get_city();
    if($city === FALSE){
        //var_dump($this->geolocation->get_error());
    }
    else{
        //var_dump($city);
        foreach ($city as $c) {
            echo $c->regionName; <-- EROR
        }
        echo "Country code : ".$city['countryName']."\n"; <-- EROR
        echo "Cityname : ".$city['cityName']."\n";  <-- EROR
    }
```

Here is value of var_dump($city)

```
string(286) "{ "statusCode" : "OK", "statusMessage" : "", "ipAddress" : "202.67.xx.xx", "countryCode" : "ID", "countryName" : "Indonesia", "regionName" : "regionblablabla", "cityName" : "cityblablabla", "zipCode" : "60132", "latitude" : "-7.258", "longitude" : "112.758", "timeZone" : "+07:00" }"
```

Eror if using foreach :

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/Front.php

Line Number: 105
```

Can you explain how to write right code to print each data. Thanks

Comment: Please be kind and tell us an error. And also show us the `var_dump($city)`

Comment: what you get in $city variable

Comment: I've edit in my question

Answer (score 0):

You are getting response in array, replace this:

```
foreach ($city as $c) { 
    echo $c->regionName;
}
```

Into:

```
foreach ($city as $c) { 
    echo "Region :".$c['regionName'];
    echo "Country code : ".$c['countryName']."\n"; 
    echo "Cityname : ".$c['cityName']."\n";
}
```

Comment: Still not work, error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @fatchul chk `print_r($city);`

Comment: Or `echo $c` inside the loop @fatchul

Comment: Not work, still  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `print_r($city);` share result @fatchul

Answer (score 0):

Your `$city` variable contains a json response. Decode it.

```
$city = json_decode($city, true);
```

You now have an array to loop through.